# Pairs of paths with the same source and target

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory, terminology, quivers

[*Commutative* diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram) usually express path equivalences in a category and thus involve pairs of paths in a category with the same source and target.

[*General* diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_%28category_theory%29) - in categories resp. category theory - do not necessarily involve pairs of paths with the same source and target.

> But is there a **name for pairs of paths with the same source and target
> in [quivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_%28mathematics%29)**?
> Pairs which only eventually are to be called
> "commutative" (expressing equivalence)?
> ("Diagram" would be a badly chosen name.)

The only commutative closed shapes that are explicitely named are "commutative triangles" and "commutative squares". So I thought about "commutative polygons" but a Google search for ["commutative polygons"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commutative%20polygons%22) gave only 10 hits.

Furthermore the question is actually only about a very restricted kind of polygons, maybe "bi-directed" polygons?

If there is no established name, I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pairs of paths with the same source and target but with no other nodes in common are called *parallel paths*, at least on the computer science side of things in graph theory -- you can google the term to get some relevant CS papers, but I couldn't find a wikipedia article on parallel paths.

If your paths are allowed to share nodes other than the source and target, I would suggest something like "piecewise parallel paths". With this terminology you can simultaneously get the idea across and score cheap points for alliteration.

As requested in the comments, here is a reference

Jwo et. al., *Characterization of node disjoint (parallel) path in star graphs* (1991) see [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/153811).

Comment: I would have appreciated a singular term - like "diagram" and not mentioning "paths" - but "parallel paths" sounds perfectly right. (I will not make the distinction between piecewise or not.)

Comment: A reference to at least *one* relevant article about "parallel paths" would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: If someone called two paths piecewise parallel, I'd probably assume that the common vertices (if any) occur in the same order along both paths.

Comment: a newer reference is Bhandari, Ramesh (1999). Survivable networks: algorithms for diverse routing 477. Springer. p. 46. ISBN 0-7923-8381-8. Efficient algorithms were initially developed by Suurballe and Tarjan.